# Post Terms As Class Name For Full Calendar Events

Tags: events, calendar

I have implemented Full Calendar via json with my Wordpress custom post types.

All is fine except I want to add the taxonomy term of the event / post to the 'className' of the event object but cant seem to get it working, can someone please take a gander at my implementation see where I am going wrong?

I cant seem to get my pasted code formatting legibly as such I have added a link to a pastebin, apologies, can be see [here](http://pastebin.com/94zDrShq)

get_single_term relates to a custom function to output the first term of the taxonomy as follows ....

```
function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy) {
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
if(!is_wp_error($terms))
{
    echo $terms[0]->name;   
} }
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `get_single_term` in a way that would require it to return a value...

```
$term = get_single_term($post->ID, 'course_locations');
```

... but you have written it in such a way that it `echo`s a value. You should have...

```
function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy) {
  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
  if(!is_wp_error($terms))
  {
    return $terms[0]->name;   
  } 
}
```

I noticed a couple of other things not directly related to the question but worth mentioning.

1. You really should be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). `include`ing `wp-load.php` like that is a kind of hack, in my opinion, that is no longer necessary. It is also prone to error. Imagine if someone were to [move one or more of the content directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder).
2. You should really learn to indent your code. You are going to run into all kinds of headaches trying to debug "flat" code like that.

Comment: good spot, working now